# Sql: Join 2 tables without common field

Tags: mysql

Hihi,

I have 2 tables that has no common field but similar field and need to join then. Basically I need to check sum of transaction during a few campaign periods

e.g.

### Table 1:

```
Campaign Name Campaign start time Campaign end time
A             2020-01-02          2020-01-04
B             2020-01-03          2020-01-04
C             2020-01-03          2020-01-09
```

### Table 2:

```
Date       Transaction ID Amount Items
2020-01-03 11             $25    3
2020-01-03 22             $24    5
2020-01-04 33             $23    1
2020-01-02 44             $22    3
2020-01-09 55             $21    3
```

I need to sum all transaction amount which their transaction Date is between campaign date.

## expected result:

```
Campaign Name Start time End time   Amount
A             2020-01-02 2020-01-04 22+23+24+25
B             2020-01-03 2020-01-04 25+24+23
C             2020-01-03 2020-01-09 25+24+23+21
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with (you can also use comparison):

```
SELECT 
    c.name,c.start,c.end, sum(t.amount) 
FROM c 
INNER JOIN t ON t.date BETWEEN c.start AND c.end 
GROUP BY (c.name)
```

Edit: As @Akina mentioned BETWEEN is well supported.